# Programmatic Alarm App in Android?

Tags: alarm

Suppose you wake up at 00:00 AM and usually have an alarm ring half-way through the day at 12:00 PM.

But now you sleep in, and wake up at 02:00 AM. Is there an app that allows for you to "reset" such alarms (and in my case there is more than one) to (in this case) find the **new** half-way point (which is 02:00 PM) for your alarm?

I don't know what else to call this except "programmatic alarms" in Android. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: This seems quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an app that does that specifically, but such a thing would be possible.

In the `Calendar` API in Android, there are values to set AM/PM for a time (`AM` and `PM`, respectively). The midpoint you speak of is the same time just with this value changed. There really isn't any formula that would have to be implemented to make this really all that programmatic. Just switch those values.

Here is the reference to the API: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

EDIT: Thinking about this a little bit more, if there is a function in the app to silence the alarm after a certain amount of time then if this extends to 12 hours (which is highly unlikely) your specific use case is covered. I think that it might be worthwhile finding an open source alarm app, editing and compiling your own version for personal use.